# What kind of chart is it? - MS Excel

Tags: excel, charts

Can someone tell me what kind of charts we see here? Or how are they connected? I know that type "0 + number" and "D + number" is a point chart. But the lines that connect them - what is that? How can I add such lines to my chart? I don't know what to write in google to find the tutorial I need.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is X Y (Scatter) chart with straight lines

[image]